# Is it possible to set Gmail to an English (Israel) locale

Tags: gmail, localization

I would like to be able to use Gmail with an English UI, but set other locale settings to the common settings in Israel (see [here](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2016/04/16/en_il-english-locale-for-israel/)). Specifically, the first day of the work week should be Sunday, and the date format is similar to the UK (dd/mm/yyyy).

So far I have used the English (UK) locale, but I noticed the snooze button shows the calendar with the wrong work week.

As a side note, in contrast to Gmail, Google Calendar has separate settings for language and country, which seem to match my needs.